# WCF specific client notification

Tags: c#, wcf

I have implemented a WCF service which many clients connect to. My problem is while sending some callback from server to client, I do not want to broadcast to every client but to individual client. How can I achieve this?
I'm aware of maintaining a dictionary of connected clients in my server, but not sure what to map them with, so that I can uniquely identify each client.

Also I'm expecting about 5000 clients to be connected to this server, is WCF a good choice for this kind of requirement?

Comment: Even if you are able to track each client by some mechanism, i am pretty sure that you cannot send "callback" (or push a message) to the client, without the client initiating a request for it in WCF.

Comment: Client is already connected. I get connect notification when the client connects first time during launch. That would suffice to send him callback right?

Comment: Can you show that part of the code where you get the notification? Is that a service caall from the client or something?

Comment: I see. And how do you plan to do a callback in it?

Comment: From the connected client context

Comment: ok seems like WCF is not suitable for this requirement. I'm going the TCP way where I can manage clients myself when they connect to socket.